Ad for following adId already exists: 13
I'm facing an issue while using Google AdMob in flutter, and I hope everyone can help.
<kbd>Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: PlatformException(error, Ad for following adId already exists: 13, null, java.lang.IllegalArgum<kbd>your text</kbd>entException: Ad for following adId already exists: 13
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.AdInstanceManager.trackAd(AdInstanceManager.java:79)
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.java:405)
at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)

> at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)</kbd>

I am not sure how to handle it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
